# jqGrid "addRowData" to "first" does not work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I cannot add a row to the top of a jqGrid table using the line:

```
jQuery("#myTable").jqGrid('addRowData', 0, myData, "first");
```

It just adds to the bottom of the list as usual

Has anyone tried this and works for them?

In my table, previously added rows have index that goes from 0 to N

I am using jqGrid v3.8.1 and jQuery 1.4.3

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        jQuery("#myTable").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            colNames: ['Data ID', 'Device'],
            colModel: [{
                    name: 'DATA_ID',
                    index: 'DATA_ID',
                    sorttype: "int",
                    width: 22,
                    align: "center",
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'DATA_DN',
                    index: 'DATA_DN',
                    width: 60,
                    align: "center",
                    sortable: false
                },
            ],
            width: "1216",

        });

        var myData = [{
            "DATA_ID": "9",
            "DATA_DN": "sony"
        }, {
            "DATA_ID": "10",
            "DATA_DN": "panasonic"
        }];
        var newData = [{
            "DATA_ID": "0",
            "DATA_DN": "national"
        }, {
            "DATA_ID": "1",
            "DATA_DN": "samsung"
        }];

        for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            jQuery("#myTable").jqGrid('addRowData', i, myData[i]);
        }

        jQuery("#myTable").addRowData(0, newData, "first");

        //jQuery("#myTable").trigger("reloadGrid");

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="myTable"></table>
    <div id="myTable_pager"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pity that you don't post the full JavaScript code which you use. So I can only guess what happens.

For example, if you define `myData` as an array (`[...]`) instead of an object (`{...}`) the position parameter will be overwritten with the value "last".

jqGrid is an open source project and you can examine what exactly do the `addRowData` function [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2569). You can exactly see in which situation the position parameter "last" will be used.

If you append your question with the code which can be used to reproduce the problem which you describes other could verify the code and either find a bug in the jqGrid or find a bug in your code. In both situation you have good chance to will be a winner.

**UPDATED** The code which you posted have some small problems.

First you should remove comma before ']' in the `colModel` definition.
Second the `newData` is an array so the last parameter will be replaced from "first" to "last".
Some other small but important problems are: you have to use `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` at the beginning of your HTML code, place the JavaScript code inside of `//<![CDATA[` ... `//]]>` and insert `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the HTML header.

The fixed code will be following

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Demonstration how programatically select grid row which are not on the first page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var grid = jQuery("#myTable");
            grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                colNames:['Data ID','Device'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'DATA_ID',index:'DATA_ID', sorttype:"int", width:22, align:"center", sortable:false},
                    {name:'DATA_DN',index:'DATA_DN', width:60, align:"center", sortable:false},
                ],
                width: "1216"
              });

            var myData = [{"DATA_ID":"9", "DATA_DN": "sony"}, {"DATA_ID":"10", "DATA_DN": "panasonic"}];
            var newData = [{"DATA_ID":"0", "DATA_DN": "national"}, {"DATA_ID":"1", "DATA_DN": "samsung"}];

            for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++) {
                grid.jqGrid('addRowData', i, myData[i]);
            }

            for (i=0;i<newData.length;i++) {
                grid.jqGrid('addRowData', myData.length+i, newData[newData.length-i-1], "first");
            }
            //grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable"><tr><td/></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

see also it live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddFirst.htm). How you can verify with [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org) the last version of HTML code is [correct](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddFirst.htm).

Nevertheless the usage of an additional hidden column which will be used for the sorting is the recommended way.

Comment: I've added the code Oleg - passing in either myData as [] or {} did not make a difference - though I found the problem - it is the call to jQuery("#myTable").trigger("reloadGrid"); that reorders the array - so the problem is with that = I do need to reload the array since my pager (not in this code) needs to be updated with the real number of records - so the question now is, how do I add new elements AND reload the grid but the rows do not get sorted - I DID used the "sortable: false" flag in the colModel...

Comment: Or (talking to myself) I could keep a recieved_time field and sort it on the basis of that so that will keep my latest records on top, as desired

Comment: @sami: The usage of recieved_time field used for sorting is a good way, but it is needed after `jQuery("#myTable").trigger("reloadGrid");`. You can add the row at any place where you want with the code which I posted.

Comment: a 'hidden column like "orderNumber"' - yes I should do that.. thanks a ton Oleg for the corrections, and advice and the live demo even - deserves +10 voteup actually :)

Comment: @Oleg: can you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352790/how-to-quickly-load-data-in-jqgrid) why isn't my `jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid('addRowData',homeFileList);` not working, if i use for loop to `addRowData` it adds data to the grid properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the grid was being reloaded and sorted after the **addRowData** call and it would sort the grid as per its sorting order - so do not call **reloadGrid** after calling **addRowData** - though the id of the news added table rows are "undefined"...

Comment: You are right. So if you use `reloadGrid` any time you should define a hidden column like "orderNumber" which will be used to hold the data in your preferred order. One more remark: it is better to append all additional information to your question as to write it in your own answer because such kind of answers will be frequently not read.