# How to quickly load data in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The problem is loading data in jqgrid takes a lot of time, currently I am using

```
for(var i=0;i<homeFileList.length;i++)
        jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,homeFileList[i]);
```

to load data into the grid, but since it is iterating, it is taking a lot of time, is there any way to load data faster?

I read the `addRowData` can even insert multiple data at once ([Reading Link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)), i thought it might be faster, but it does not insert anything to my grid

See my below code.

```
var homeFileList=[];
$(xml).find('IPC').each(function(){ 
    $(this).children('homefilelist').each(function(){ 
        $(this).children('homefilelist_info').each(function(){ 
            var row={};
            isPresent=true;
            row.permission=$(this).attr('permission');
            row.hardlink=$(this).attr('hardlink');
            row.owner=$(this).attr('owner');
            row.group=$(this).attr('group');
            row.fsize=$(this).attr('fsize');
            row.month=$(this).attr('month');
            row.date=$(this).attr('date');
            row.time=$(this).attr('time');
            row.filename=$(this).attr('filename');
            homeFileList.push(row);
        });
    });
});
```

**Update after Oleg's comment**

```
//HomeFileList
if(homeFileList.length>0)
{
    jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid({
        datatype: "clientSide",
        colNames:['Permission','Hardlink','Owner','Group','Size','Month','Date','Year/Time','Filename'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'permission',index:'permission', align:"left",width:"100px"}, 
            {name:'hardlink',index:'hardlink', align:"left", width:"80px"},
            {name:'owner',index:'owner', align:"left",width:"100px"},
            {name:'group',index:'group', align:"left"},
            {name:'fsize',index:'fsize', align:"left", width:"90px"},
            {name:'month',index:'month', align:"left",width:"100px"},   
            {name:'date',index:'date', align:"left", width:"80px"},
            {name:'time',index:'time', align:"left",width:"100px"},
            {name:'filename',index:'filename', align:"left"}
        ],

                    pager : '#HomeFileListGridpager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,50,100],
        scrollOffset:0,
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true
            });

    /*This for loop loads my data from homeFileList into grid
for(var i=0;i<homeFileList.length;i++)
        jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,homeFileList[i]);*/

    alert($.isArray(homeFileList)); //returns true


    jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid('addRowData',homeFileList);


    jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
else
    gridUnavailable("#tblHomeFileList");
```

XML response (I have cut short the xml below, as it is huge data inside `homefilelist`)

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="client9.xsl"?><client version="1.0"><IPC>
<homefilelist>
    <homefilelist_info permission='-rwxr-xr-x' hardlink='1' owner='asimon' group='support' fsize='61597' month='Mar' date='22' time='2011' filename='libpmwspsvrcmn.so' />
    <homefilelist_info permission='-rwxr-xr-x' hardlink='1' owner='asimon' group='support' fsize='21778' month='Mar' date='22' time='2011' filename='libpmorablk.so' />
    <homefilelist_info permission='-rwxr-xr-x' hardlink='1' owner='asimon' group='support' fsize='36226' month='Mar' date='22' time='2011' filename='libpmjvm.so' />
</homefilelist>
</IPC>
</client>
```

Comment: Could you insert XML data which one can use as input for the grid during the tests. Moreover I wrote you before that there are no jqGrid options with the name `pagination`, `edit`, `add` or `del`. Why you use there?

Comment: @Oleg: ok I have removed the unnecessary options and updated my question with my xml response. (though this response is cut short to accomodate in my question, there are 100's of `homefilelist_info` tag inside `homefilelist` tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data` parameter of jqGrid:

```
$("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: homeFileList,
    ...
});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Ricky-XML.htm). In the case the *whole* data of the grid will be placed in the grid and the first page will be paint. I am sure that you will see the difference in the performance for large number of rows immediately.

I recommend you additionally include `formatter` and `sorttype` attributes in the grid. For example the definition of `'fsize'` which hold integer data can be the following:

```
{name: 'fsize', index: 'fsize', width: 90, formatter: 'integer', sorttype: 'int'}
```

Comment: Thanks the data loads comparatively faster

Comment: @Ricky: You mean faster, but not fast enough? How many rows you added? How many time get creating of the grid with the data? You can measure the exact time with `var startTime = new Date();` before the grid creating and `var totalTime = new Date() - startTime;` after the grid is created. `totalTime` will show you exact time interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your data into JSON/XML you can quickly add it by using the undocumented `jqGrid.p.data` attribute and just setting it, then reloading the grid.  You need to make sure that your data already conforms to the columns you have mapped.

```
if(_theGrid == undefined) {
    _theGrid = $("#list3").jqGrid({...});
}
else {
    _theGrid.p.data = data;
    $(_theGrid).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Comment: I am getting the data in xml format, but this data is being used elsewhere too, so I am using `datatype: "clientSide"` to get data from a variable. My question is why isn't `jQuery("#tblHomeFileList").jqGrid('addRowData',homeFileList);` working?

Comment: @Ricky I have added an example.  I overlooked you weren't setting the data initially, and instead thought you were trying to reload a different data set.  My example is useful for those wishing to update the data to a new dataset (useful for AJAX calls).